# Redirect file upload to another server with Spring Web

Tags: spring-mvc, kotlin, multipartform-data

Redirect file upload to another server with Spring Web

I have a server application based on Spring MVC (not Spring Boot). It is developed in Kotlin. This application should process a very specific upload request. All it should do is forward this request to another server. So the RestController works like a proxy. Is it possible to create this functionality with Spring resources alone or is a third party library required?

The RestController may look like this. It provides an endpoint for a file upload (multipart form data). The addtional parameter resourceId is used together with the injected baseApiUrl to create the url to the external server which is the final recipient of the upload.

```
@RestController
class UploadForwarderRestController(
        @Value("#{environmentProps['externalService.base-api-url']}") baseApiUrl: String
) {

    @PostMapping(
            value = ["/myresource/{resourceId}"],
            consumes = [MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE],
            produces = [MediaType.ALL_VALUE]
    )
    fun forwardUpload(
            @RequestParam myResource: MultipartFile,
            @PathVariable resourceId: Int
    ): ResponseEntity<Any?> {

        // ...

    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this in one go or does the RestController have to cache the file before it can be forwarded to the target server?